# Verify: Prove $g=h$ if $g \circ f = h\circ f$ and $f$ is onto

Tags: abstract-algebra

This is a question from Edbert Walker's abstract algebra text, which I am independently studying.

> **Lemma I**
> Let $f$ be a function from $A$ to $B$ and let $g, h$ be functions from $B$ to $C$. Show that if $g \circ f = h\circ f$ and $f$ is onto, then $g=h$
>
> **Lemma II**
> Let $g,h$ be functions from $A$ to $B$ and $f$ be a function from $B$ to $C$. Show that if $f \circ g = f\circ h$ and $f$ is injective, then $g=h$

I'm hoping these simple proofs can be verified.

> **Lemma I**
> Let $b \in B$. $f$ being onto furnishes an $a$ such that $f(a)=b$. Looking back at $g \circ f = h \circ f$, shows $g(b = f(a)) = h(b=f(a))$ for any choice of $b$. Therefore $g=h$.
>
> **Lemma II**
> Let $a \in A$. Since by hypothesis $f\circ g = f\circ h$, $f(h(a)) = f(g(a))$. $f$ is injective so we conclude $h(a) = g(a)$.

Is this a sound proof?

Comment: Fun fact: This property actually characterises onto functions, without ever referring to the elements of the underlying sets. There is a dual (reverse) version characterising one-to-one functions.

Comment: Sounds interesting! I don't quite understand what you are saying. Would you mind elaborating that?

Comment: A function $f$ from $A$ to $B$ is onto iff, given any $C$, two functions $g,h$ from $B$ to $C$ are equal iff their respective compositions with $f$ are. Injectivity is similar, except $g,h$ go from $C$ to $A$ instead of from $B$ to $C$.

Comment: Basically, what he is saying is that there is a more general framework, called category theory, in which we study the abstract constructions of mathematics and the relations between them. If we work in the category of sets, for instance, we want to prove very general statements about sets and functions between them without ever referring to a particular set and its elements. It turns out, as he points out, that surjectivity and injectivity are properties that can be described purely in terms of functions, and not in terms of elements inside sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's written a bit awkwardly, but you have the right idea.

> $f$ being onto furnishes an $a$ such that $f(a)=b$ for any $b$.

Here the order of quantifiers make it sound like a single $a$ will yield any $b$ through $f$ (which of course makes no sense if $f$ is to be a function). I would write something like

> Let $b \in B$. Since $f$ is onto, there exists $a \in A$ such that $f(a) = b$.

Then, the usage of the two inner equal signs in

> $g(b = f(a)) = h(b=f(a))$

is very nonstandard. I would just write something like

> Since $g\circ f = h \circ f$ by hypothesis, we must therefore have $g(b) = g(f(a)) = h(f(a)) = h(b)$.

---

For the injectivity proof:

You talk about $a$ and $c$ without even saying what they are first. But there really is no point in even introducing those variables if you don't need them. I would simply write something like

> Let $a \in A$. Since $f \circ g = f \circ h$ by hypothesis, applying this function to $a$ yields $f(g(a)) = f(h(a))$. But $f$ is injective, which implies that $g(a) = h(a)$. Since this holds for any $a \in A$, we conclude that $g = h$.

---

So, in short: your ideas are sound, but remember to introduce all the symbols that you are using (but without introducing any unnecessary notation!), and try to be as concise as possible while still justifying every step as clearly as you can.

Comment: Is there a deeper reason why the injective proof is precisely the opposite of the onto proof?

Comment: @theideasmith Yes, and it's related to my comments to your questions above. In the framework of category theory (basically the study of functions in its most abstract form, only arguing about compositions and equality of functions, and not about the actual elements that the functions work on), injectivity and surjectivity (onto) are so-called dual notions (in this framework called monomorphisms and epimorphisms, respectively). It means that if you take the definition of one of them, write it out, and then reverse the direction of every single function mentioned, then you get the other.

Comment: @theideasmith Good question! In categorical terms, an injective function is precisely a *monomorphism* in the category of sets. Since this notion concerns only arrows (functions) between objects (sets), one may reverse all the arrows to obtain a so-called dual notion. The dual notion of a monomorphism is an *epimorphism*, and corresponds precisely to a surjective function in the category of sets.

Comment: Thanks so much guys for explaining this. I'm starting to see how powerfully one can understand structure with abstract algebra. Re injectivity and surjectivity being dual notions: does this relate to the composition being a group operation?

Comment: Composition generally isn't even a binary operation: one needs to restrict to maps with the same domain and codomain in order to get a binary operation $\circ: \operatorname{Maps}(X,X) \times \operatorname{Maps}(X,X) \to \operatorname{Maps}(X,X)$. In category theory, one relaxes this condition to allow a general composition of arrows of the form $\circ: \operatorname{Hom}(Y,Z) \times \operatorname{Hom}(X,Y) \to \operatorname{Hom}(X,Z)$. In this setting, duality is a functor between categories that preserves objects and turns each $\operatorname{Hom}(X,Y)$ into $\operatorname{Hom}(Y,X)$.

Answer (score 1):

The notation $g(b = f(a))$ is not standard - I probably would have written
$$
g(b) = g(f(a)) = h(f(a)) = h(b),
$$
but your proof is sound.

As for the dual proof, you again have the right idea, but it could be a bit clearer/cleaner. In particular, you might elaborate on the second sentence: "because $f\circ g = f\circ h$, $f(g(a)) = (f\circ g)(a) = (f\circ h)(a) = f(h(a))$. Thus, by injectivity of $f$, $g(a) = h(a)$, and since $a\in A$ was arbitrary, this shows $g = h$." Note that when you present the proof like this, there is no need to introduce the extra notation of $b_1$, $b_2$, and $c$ (which really don't serve a purpose, and only serve as extra notation one must keep track of).

Comment: That is good to know!

Comment: I know it is annoying to answer and then see that the question is edited but I've just edited the question

Comment: @theideasmith edited to address the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Why not trying the straightforward proof?

We want to prove $g=h$ so we need to prove $(\forall x). g(x)=h(x)$

So start with an arbitrary member  $b\in B$. Since $f$ is onto we have  $\exists a\in A \quad  s.t. \quad f(a)=b$.

$g(b)=g(f(a))=h(f(a))=h(b)$

Comment: Isn't that esentially what I did, albeit in less straighforward language?

Comment: @theideasmith Of course. I'm just saying we can do it more straightforward.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'm pretty new to proof based math and have been learning on my own. This has precluded my proofs from being critiqued by an outside authority (until SO). But I'm learning from people like you who are kind enough to point out such things as necessary.